# Can't print on LCD

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, lcd, serial-data

I'm a newbie here. And sorry for my bad English first of all.

Right now I'm working on VLC (Visible Light Communication). I have working code, in which output is displayed on the Serial Monitor. But now I want to print this output on an LCD.

I made necessary changes like including the LCD library and instead of `Serial.print` I used `lcd.print`. But nothing is displayed on the LCD.

Here is the modified code including LCD:

```
static int TRESHOLD = 500;
static unsigned int standardDelay = 13500000; //1350 is limit
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 7,6,5,4);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // 9600 bits per second
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT); //digital PWM 3 on output
  int sensorValue = 0;
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // initialize the serial communications:
}

void loop() {
  WriteChar('h');
  WriteChar('e');
  WriteChar('l');
  WriteChar('l');
  WriteChar('o');
  WriteChar('w');
  WriteChar('o');
  WriteChar('r');
  WriteChar('l');
  WriteChar('d');
}

void WriteChar(char str){
  switch (str - '0'){
    case 49:
      //code for a is 011 0001
      LightFlash(false, true, true, false, false, false, true);
      break;
    case 50:
      //code for b is 011 0010
      LightFlash(false, true, true, false, false, true, false);
      break;
    case 51:
      //code for c is 011 0011
      LightFlash(false, true, true, false, false, true, true);
      break;
    case 52:
      //code for d is 011 0100
      LightFlash(false, true, true, false, true, false, false);
      break;
    case 53:
      //code for e is 011 0101
      LightFlash(false, true, true, false, true, false, true);
      break;
    case 54:
      //code for f is 011 0110
      LightFlash(false, true, true, false, true, true, false);
      break;
    case 55:
      //code for g is 011 0111
      LightFlash(false, true, true, false, true, true, true);
      break;
    case 56:
      //code for h is 011 1000
      LightFlash(false, true, true, true, false, false, false);
      break;
    case 57:
      //code for i is 011 1001
      LightFlash(false, true, true, true, false, false, true);
      break;
    case 58:
      //code for j is 011 1010
      LightFlash(false, true, true, true, false, true, false);
      break;
    case 59:
      //code for k is 011 1011
      LightFlash(false, true, true, true, false, true, true);
      break;
    case 60:
      //code for l is 011 1100
      LightFlash(false, true, true, true, true, false, false);
      break;
    case 61:
      //code for m is 011 1101
      LightFlash(false, true, true, true, true, false, true);
      break;
    case 62:
      //code for n is 011 1110
      LightFlash(false, true, true, true, true, true, false);
      break;
    case 63:
      //code for o is 011 1111
      LightFlash(false, true, true, true, true, true, true);
      break;
    case 64:
      //code for p is 100 0000
      LightFlash(true, false, false, false, false, false, false);
      break;
    case 65:
      //code for q is 100 0001
      LightFlash(true, false, false, false, false, false, true);
      break;
    case 66:
      //code for r is 100 0010
      LightFlash(true, false, false, false, false, true, false);
      break;
    case 67:
      //code for s is 100 0011
      LightFlash(true, false, false, false, false, true, true);
      break;
    case 68:
      //code for t is 100 0100
      LightFlash(true, false, false, false, true, false, false);
      break;
    case 69:
      //code for u is 100 0101
      LightFlash(true, false, false, false, true, false, true);
      break;
    case 70:
      //code for v is 100 0110
      LightFlash(true, false, false, false, true, true, false);
      break;
    case 71:
      //code for w is 100 0111
      LightFlash(true, false, false, false, true, true, true);
      break;
    case 72:
      //code for x is 100 1000
      LightFlash(true, false, false, true, false, false, false);
      break;
    case 73:
      //code for y is 100 1001
      LightFlash(true, false, false, true, false, false, true);
      break;
    case 74:
      //code for z is 100 1010
      LightFlash(true, false, false, true, false, true, false);
      break;
    default:
      lcd.print(str - '0');
      lcd.print("CAME IN DEFAULT IN WRITECHAR");
      break;
  }
}

void LightFlash(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c, boolean d, boolean e, boolean f, boolean g){


  digitalWrite(3,LOW);
  if (a == true){
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  }
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);
  boolean sensorValue1 = (analogRead(A0)>TRESHOLD);
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);

  digitalWrite(3,LOW);
  if (b == true){
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  }
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);
  boolean sensorValue2 = (analogRead(A0)>TRESHOLD);
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);

  digitalWrite(3,LOW);
  if (c == true){
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  }
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);
  boolean sensorValue3 = (analogRead(A0)>TRESHOLD);
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);

  digitalWrite(3,LOW);
  if (d == true){
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  }
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);
  boolean sensorValue4 = (analogRead(A0)>TRESHOLD);
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);

  digitalWrite(3,LOW);
  if (e == true){
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  }
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);
  boolean sensorValue5 = (analogRead(A0)>TRESHOLD);
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);

  digitalWrite(3,LOW);
  if (f == true){
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  }
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);
  boolean sensorValue6 = (analogRead(A0)>TRESHOLD);
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);

  digitalWrite(3,LOW);
  if (g == true){
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  }
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);
  boolean sensorValue7 = (analogRead(A0)>TRESHOLD);
  delayMicroseconds(standardDelay/2);
  delayMicroseconds(3*standardDelay); //1 second passed

  long result = 0;
  result = 1000000*sensorValue1 + 100000*sensorValue2 + 10000*sensorValue3
  + 1000*sensorValue4 + 100*sensorValue5 + 10*sensorValue6 + 1*sensorValue7;
  //lcd.print(result);
  PrintChar(result);
}


void PrintChar(long binary){

  switch (binary){

    case 110001:
      //code for a is 011 0001 
      lcd.write("a");
      break;
    case 110010:
      //code for b is 011 0010          
      lcd.print("b");
      break;
    case 110011:
      //code for c is 011 0011          
      lcd.print("c");
      break;
    case 110100:
      //code for d is 011 0100          
      lcd.print("d");
      break;
    case 110101:
      //code for e is 011 0101
      lcd.print("e");
      break;
    case 110110:
      //code for f is 011 0110
      lcd.print("f");
      break;
    case 110111:
      //code for g is 011 0111
      lcd.print("g");
      break;
    case 111000:
      //code for h is 011 1000
      lcd.print("h");
      break;
    case 111001:
      //code for i is 011 1001
      lcd.print("i");
      break;
    case 111010:
      //code for j is 011 1010
      lcd.print("j");
      break;
    case 111011:
      //code for k is 011 1011
      lcd.print("k");
      break;
    case 111100:
      //code for l is 011 1100
      lcd.print("l");
      break;
    case 111101:
      //code for m is 011 1101
      lcd.print("m");
      break;
    case 111110:
      //code for n is 011 1110
      lcd.print("n");
      break;
    case 111111:
      //code for o is 011 1111
      lcd.print("o");
      break;
    case 1000000:
      //code for p is 100 0000
      lcd.print("p");
      break;
    case 1000001:
      //code for q is 100 0001
      lcd.print("q");
      break;
    case 1000010:
      //code for r is 100 0010
      lcd.print("r");
      break;
    case 1000011:
      //code for s is 100 0011
      lcd.print("s");
      break;
    case 1000100:
      //code for t is 100 0100
      lcd.print("t");
      break;
    case 1000101:
      //code for u is 100 0101
      lcd.print("u");
      break;
    case 1000110:
      //code for v is 100 0110
      lcd.print("v");
      break;
    case 1000111:
      //code for w is 100 0111
      lcd.print("w");
      break;
    case 1001000:
      //code for x is 100 1000
      lcd.print("x");
      break;
    case 1001001:
      //code for y is 100 1001
      lcd.print("y");
      break;
    case 1001010:
      //code for z is 100 1010
      lcd.print("z");
      break;
    case 11000:
      lcd.print("dit gebeurt vaak");
      break;
    case 1011001:
      lcd.print("dit ook");
      break;
    case 100001:
      lcd.print("tenslotte dit nog");
      break;
    case 1011000:
      lcd.print("en dit is de laatste denk ik");
      break;
    default:
      lcd.print(binary);
      lcd.print("CAME IN DEFAULT ON PRINTCHAR");
      break;
  }
}
```

I want to print this output on LCD. But I'm not able to do that. Please help me out.

Circuits:

(1) VLC Circuit

[image: VLC Circuit]

(2) LCD Circuit

[image: LCD Circuit]

I combined both circuits above and made a final circuit.

The VLC circuit is set up in which DATA is transmitted from SIMPLE LED and Capture on PHOTODIODE. And using LCD Circuit I want to display data on LCD.

Comment: I don't see any code related to the LCD.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Becuase I remove it and upload original code. Already I mention that thing. Just check it out above the code. Ok...

Comment: Not enough information. Post your LCD code and schematics.

Comment: @LookAlterno Ok, let me.

Comment: Connecting a LCD display to an Arduino is not easy because of all those wires and the contrast and the cheap displays need enough voltage (above 4.5 V). I had some trouble with it myself. The second time it was a piece of cake. Forget your project for a moment and make a sketch that only uses the LCD. Start here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystal

Comment: @Jot Thank you for your advice. I also try out so much code of LCD. Connection setup is all right. But not able to find out what's wrong happen with my code. I uploaded the latest code with. Please check out.

Comment: I did. Please make an other small test sketch, just for the display. Your sketch has conflicting things for characters, binary and values. Some improvements can make it easier. But first try to get something on the display. The wires are connected to other pins than in your sketch.

Comment: @Jot How? Because I think the whole sketch is necessary. I can't able to make some small sketch.

Comment: Of course you can. Make another sketch, a small test sketch that writes "hello" to the lcd display. If that is working, then you know that the display is wired okay and the contrast is okay.

Comment: @Jot Oh, you are to say that make simple LCD code which displays "Hello" word. I already do that. And working fine.

Comment: I think you ascii conversion is wrong. Ascii code for "h" is 110 1000, and you are using 011 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got the problem. My code is working fine. I have a problem with my LCD connection.

I write

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 7, 6, 5, 4);
```

Instead of

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is so many problems with your code. It can be so much short.

Take WriteChar. Why mess with binary value for chars? Use char directly, just here:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WriteChar('h');
  WriteChar('e');
}

void loop() {
}

void WriteChar(char c) {
  boolean b7 = c & B1000000;
  boolean b6 = c & B0100000;
  boolean b5 = c & B0010000;
  boolean b4 = c & B0001000;
  boolean b3 = c & B0000100;
  boolean b2 = c & B0000010;
  boolean b1 = c & B0000001;

  Serial.println(c);
  LightFlash(b7, b6, b5, b4, b3, b2, b1);

}

void LightFlash(boolean b7, boolean b6, boolean b5, boolean b4, boolean b3, boolean b2, boolean b1) {
  Serial.print(b7 ? "1" : "0");  
  Serial.print(b6 ? "1" : "0");  
  Serial.print(b5 ? "1" : "0");  
  Serial.print(b4 ? "1" : "0");  
  Serial.print(b3 ? "1" : "0");  
  Serial.print(b2 ? "1" : "0");  
  Serial.println(b1 ? "1" : "0");  
}
```

There is more simply ways to write that (using arrays and loops) but this is easier to understand. And better, pass the char directly to LightBlash.

Don't use a string when you just pass a char to a function.